# MYSQL merge same rows but update one field(like sum) while merging rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sum

Iam really new to MYSQL.My problem is I have some table like this

```
date         pagePath         pageviews
2020-01-01   /service/1         5
2020-01-01   /service/1         8
2020-01-02   /service/2         5

date         pagePath         pageviews
2020-01-01   /service/1         13
2020-01-02   /service/2         5
```

So basically I want to merge all the rows which have same date,pagePath but add up pageviews.

Comment: GROUP BY and SUM.

Comment: @forpas can you send me the code snippet? I am not able to perform that operation. It says "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: *merge all the rows which have same date,pagePath* means `group by date,pagePath`

Comment: @forpas select date,pagePath,sum(pageviews) from datatable group by date,pagePath;

Comment: This is it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query:

```
select date, pagePath, sum(pageViews) pageViews
from mytable
group by date, pagePath
```

Comment: This is working! Can I add where clause for dates? something like this select date,pagePath,sum(pageviews) from datatable where date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-07' group by date,pagePath;

Comment: @AzharSyed: yes, you can add a `where` clause, your syntax is correct.